# Using sDNA python interface

Tags: sdna

I am trying to perform road network analysis with sDNA. I have successfully generated a shapefile with all centrality measures I need using the following command in the python shell

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "c:\Program Files\sDNA\bin\sdnaintegral.py" --im 
"net=C:\...\inputfile.shp" --om "net=C:\...\outputfile.shp" start_gs=; 
end_gs=;metric=ANGULAR ;radii=n;arcxytol=; arcztol=;custommetric=;disable=;; 
origweight=;destweight=;weight_type=Link;cont;nojunctions;nohull
```

But what I really want is to use the python interface explained in the **runcalculation.py** file (which comes within the installation folder). In it, a function called **runcalculation** is defined. It takes six arguments: env, name, config_string, input_map, output_map and dll. I guess the following would work for the last four items:

```
config_string = 'start_gs=;end_gs=;metric=ANGULAR; radii=n; arcxytol=; 
arcztol=; custommetric=;disable=;;origweight=;destweight=;weight_type=Link; 
cont; nojunctions;nohull’
input_map = {‘net’:’ C:\...\inputfile.shp’}
output_map = {‘net’: C: \outputfile.shp} 
dll=’’
```

but I can not infer the contents of env (environment object) and name.

1. Would you please provide me with an example to see how those two parameters should look like?
2. Will I be able to obtain all centrality measures at once as with **sdnaintegral.py** through this function **runcalculation**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal use `runcalculation` is called from `commandline_integral_prepare.py` so the definitive example of how to use it can be found there, and yes, it will produce all measures. The latter is easier to comprehend if you know that there were originally separate scripts for `sdnaintegral.py` and `sdnaprepare.py`. `commandline_integral_prepare` is now called with a single name argument `"sdnaintegral"` or "`sdnaprepare`" to parse command line options and call `runcalculation`.

The same name (integral/prepare) is the second argument you are looking for, in your case `"sdnaintegral"`.

`env` is the environment sDNA runs in and is either an ArcGIS/arcpy environment (for which an ArcGIS installation is needed, but it can read geodatabases) or a plain shapefile environment which is self-contained.

To create a shapefile environment:

```
import sdna_environment
env = sdna_environment.SdnaShapefileEnvironment(spatial_reference_source)
```

`spatial_reference_source` is the feature class from which spatial referencing information is read, and should be the same as your input file, in your case `inputfile.shp`.

To create an ArcGIS environment:

```
import sdna_environment
env = sdna_environment.SdnaArcpyEnvironment(spatial_reference_source)
```

In ArcGIS it is conventional that tolerance information is read with spatial reference information, if you wish to do this you can pass it on to sDNA as follows

```
from arc_utils import get_tolerance,get_z_tolerance
tol = get_tolerance(spatial_reference_source)
ztol = get_z_tolerance(spatial_reference_source)
config_string += ";arcxytol=%f;arcztol=%f;"%(tol,ztol)
```

`sdna_environment.py` and `arc_utils.py` are also found in the sDNA installation folder.

Finally, I don't know your use case but if you wanted to work from networks in memory instead of shapefiles you could look at how `runcalculation.py` uses `sdnapy.py`.